# Smart plug and switch

Tags: data, datalogger

how can I switch the plug using another adaptor?
I have used a data logger in a hot water tank which has digital output that can act on the relays and control appliances. Moreover there is   a pump inside the tank for circulating water. I want to use the digital outputs of data logger and by switching the relays controls this pump, i.e switching it off/on. One possible way is using smart plug and use digital output remotely to change it but there is no WIFI or modem there. I heard about another possible solution , which is using a plug/socket that could connect to this data logger and to make it on/off with DC current. Does anybody has a knowledge about it?
let me explain it better: the datalogger has digital output trough which we can work on relay and activate or deactivate the pump. So I am looking for a plug and socket that toggle with 24 V DC power so that data logger can work with it and therefore we can change the digital output.